# youtube upload video, 403 when requesting None returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a video to youtube using python.
Using the example code from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert
I am getting an error while uploading.

```py
class YTService():

  def __init__(self, credentials):
    # Youtube Credential
    self._YOUTUBE_SERVICE = build(
        YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME,
        YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
        http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

  def initialize_upload(self, buffer):
    if not buffer:
      return

    tags = None
    if _YOUTUBE_OPTIONS.get('keywords'):
      tags = _YOUTUBE_OPTIONS.get('keywords').split(',')

    body = dict(
        snippet=dict(
            title=_YOUTUBE_OPTIONS.get('title'),
            description=_YOUTUBE_OPTIONS.get('description'),
            tags=tags,
            categoryId=_YOUTUBE_OPTIONS.get('category')),
        status=dict(privacyStatus=_YOUTUBE_OPTIONS.get('privacyStatus')))
    print("{0} in initialize_upload".format(body))
    # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    insert_request = self._YOUTUBE_SERVICE.videos().insert(
        part=','.join(body.keys()),
        body=body,
        media_body=MediaInMemoryUpload(
            buffer, mimetype='video/mp4', chunksize=-1, resumable=True))

    return self.resumable_upload(insert_request)

  # This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
  # failed upload.
  def resumable_upload(self, insert_request):
    response = None
    error = None
    retry = 0
    youtube_id = None
    while response is None:
      try:
        _, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
        print("response : {0} in resumable_upload".format(response))
        if response is not None:
          if 'id' in response:
            youtube_id = response['id']
            return youtube_id
          else:
            exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)
      except HttpError as e:
        if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
          error = 'A retriable HTTP error {} occurred:\n{}'.format(
              e.resp.status, e.content)
        else:
          raise

      except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS as e:
        error = 'A retriable error occurred: {}'.format(e)

      if error is not None:
        retry += 1
        if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
          raise ValueError('No longer attempting to retry.')

        max_sleep = 2 * retry
        sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
        print('YouTube sleeping {} seconds and then retrying...'.format(
            sleep_seconds))
        time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
    return youtube_id

  def get_youtube_id(self, buffer, title):
    if len(title) > 100:
      title = title[0:100]
    if title:
      _YOUTUBE_OPTIONS['title'] = title
    return self.initialize_upload(buffer)
```

> <HttpError 403 when requesting None returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]

It is accessed using the ouath2.0 client and the scope is

```py
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner'
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
```

I put 4 of them.

What could be the problem?

hope the video is uploaded

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] so that others can see what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Means that your application has not requested the proper consent from the user

The [videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) method requires that your application use an access token which has been authorized with one of the following scopes

[image]

Now you have stated that you have those scopes in your code.  May i sugest that you changed the scopes in your code and added these after you had already authorized the user, with a lower level scope.

You need to remove your old authorization and request authorization of the user again using the new scopes.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply..I have one more question, but I'm trying to upload a video to the brand account's channel.
I heard that onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel can be used with this parameter, can you tell me how to use it in the python client?

Comment: @JayJHongilJo remember to accept the answer if it helped you. You could open a new question regarding onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel